# How to give method name in startup in wpf app.xaml file.

Tags: wpf

```
void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs args)
    {
         this.Resources = new OfficeStyle();
    }
```

i have given this method name as Startup="App_Startup" in app.xaml file

when i run the program it gives me error that "Cannot locate resource app_startup" 
[image]

Comment: Share APP. XAML for more refeence

Answer (score 1):

I think, in your **App.xaml** you have something like:

```
StartupUri="app_startup"
```

But you need set **StartupUri** to some window.xaml like

```
<Application
    ...
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
    Startup="App_Startup"
   ...
>
</Application>
```

Comment: thank vppuzakov..i had used Startup="App_Startup" in my App.xaml code...but did't set StartupUri,..which  later on i set in App.xaml.cs page in OnStartup method.. and now its working as expected..!!